# Unsure what is causing my linked-list data to be lost between functions

Tags: c

I am trying to write a linked list which is being accessed by two functions, one which creates nodes and appends to the list and one which searches and removes from the list. I also have a separate function which initializes the memory for the list and each node. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
static mbox *send_recv;    // global statement

void mbox_create(mbox **mb)  // list creation
{
    *mb = malloc(sizeof(mbox));
    sem_init(&(*mb)->sem_mbox, 1);
    (*mb)->msg_queue = NULL;
}

void send(int tid, char *msg, int len)
{
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        mbox_create(&send_recv);
        flag = 1;
    }

    char* msg1 = malloc(1024);
    int a = len;

    struct msg *temp = send_recv->msg_queue;
    struct msg *temp1 = GetNewMsgNode(a);

    // copy message into a temp variable
    strcpy(msg1, msg);

    //lock the send-recv mailbox
    sem_wait(send_recv->sem_mbox);

    if(temp == NULL)
    {
        temp1->sender = tid;
        strcpy(temp1->message, msg1);
        temp1->next = NULL;

        temp = temp1;
    }
    else
    {
        // traverse to the last node again of the mailbox and insert the new node
        while(temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp->next;

        // set the sender's tid to the newly deposited message
        temp = temp->next;

        temp1->sender = tid;
        strcpy(temp1->message, msg1);
        temp1->next = NULL;

        temp = temp1;
    }

    // unlock the send-recv mailbox
    sem_signal(send_recv->sem_mbox);

}

void receive(int *tid, char *msg, int *len)
{
    struct msg *temp = send_recv->msg_queue;
    struct msg *temp1;
    char *msg1 = malloc(1024);

    if(*tid == 0)       // if tid = 0, receive the first message from the mailbox if the mailbox is not empty
    {
        // lock the send-recv mailbox
        sem_wait(send_recv->sem_mbox);

        if(flag == 0)       // if the send() was never called, means the mailbox is empty
        {
            *len = 0;
            *tid = 0;
        }
        else if(temp != NULL)
        {
            *len = temp->length;
            strcpy(msg1, temp->message);

            if(send_recv->msg_queue->next != NULL)
                send_recv->msg_queue = send_recv->msg_queue->next;

        }
        // unlock the send-recv mailbox
        sem_signal(send_recv->sem_mbox);

        // copy the message back into the original pointer, ie, msg
        strcpy(msg, msg1);
    }
    else      // search the mailbox for a message with the matching tid in the sender's field and retrieve that message, if mailbox is not empty
    {
        // lock the send-recv mailbox
        sem_wait(send_recv->sem_mbox);

        if(flag == 0)       // if the send() was never called, means the mailbox is empty
        {
            *len = 0;
            *tid = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(send_recv->msg_queue->sender == *tid)
            {
                *len = send_recv->msg_queue->length;
                strcpy(msg1, send_recv->msg_queue->message);

                // delete the above message from the mailbox

                if(send_recv->msg_queue->next != NULL)
                    send_recv->msg_queue = send_recv->msg_queue->next;

                free(temp);

            }
            else
            {
                // traverse the mailbox queue to find a matching message
                while(temp->next != NULL)
                {
                    if(temp->sender == *tid)
                    {
                        *len = temp->length;
                        strcpy(msg1, temp->message);

                        // delete the above message from the mailbox

                        temp1 = temp->next;
                        temp->length = temp1->length;
                        temp->sender = temp1->sender;
                        temp->receiver = temp1->receiver;
                        strcpy(temp->message, temp1->message);
                        temp->next = temp1->next;

                     //   free(temp1);

                    }
                    else
                        temp = temp->next;

                }

            }

        }
        // unlock the send-recv mailbox
        sem_signal(send_recv->sem_mbox);

        // copy the message back into the original pointer , ie, msg
        strcpy(msg, msg1);
    }
}
```

The send() function works as expected and deposits the correct messages into the list. However, when the receive function attempts to scan the list to retrieve, it finds the list empty! I am unsure what I am missing here. I know it is something very small .... but I would appreciate some help here!

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
strcpy(msg1, msg);
```

will not work very well. Remember that strings are terminated by the first zero byte, so if the structure contains any zero (like a `int` with any containing byte with a zero, or a pointer, or just anything that can contain a zero) `strcpy` will stop.

Don't use string functions with non-string data.In this case I guess you might want [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

You should, incidentally, get a warning from the `strcpy` call, as one pointer is not correct. Also, why allocate all of `1024` bytes instead of `sizeof(struct msg)`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, that is not the problem here because msg and msg1 are indeed strings. I am finding the entire mbox send_recv empty while the program calls receive() after it has called send() earlier.

Comment: @user2784743 The `msg` structure can not be a string! It can *contain* strings, but it isn't a string.